# RegExp where description starts with a specific word and then contains title

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am a beginner learning how to use RegExp in SQL . I want to figure out a way to write a RegExp expression when I have two fields called title and description. Lets say that the title is a name (ex: John, Mary) and the description always follows the template "Hello *title*" (ex: Hello John, Hello Mary). I know that I can can get around it with:

```
REGEXP(description, r'^Hello') 
AND description CONTAINS title
```

but I was hoping to be able to have a more specific regular expression, something like:

```
REGEXP(description, r'^Hello' title)
```

Comment: If title is `John`, should it match `Hello Mr. John Doe`, or should it only match `Hello John` and nothing else?

Comment: @Andreas, it should also match "Hello John Doe..." and any number of words following that. Thanks!

Comment: Since `title` is a value from the table, you can't use `REGEXP`, so what you have (`REGEXP and CONTAINS`) is the best you'll get.

Comment: @Andreas, ah I see. That's too bad, but thanks for your help! :)

Comment: why is it tagged [tag:mysql]?